# Using sed to trim the beginning of stdout

Tags: regex, bash, macos, sed

I'm writing a small script to list all the directories being shared in a macos system. Macos has a simple tool called `sharing -l` that will list all the paths once it's combined with `sharing -l | grep path` The problem is the output looks like this:

`path:      /Volumes/Storage A/File Server/`

and I need it to look like this instead

`/Volumes/Storage\ A/File\ Server/`

So the white spaces need to be escaped and the beginning of the line with path: and the white space needs to be trimmed. I'm been messing about with sed for hours now but I just don't know enough about it to do this all in one command. I'm hoping to append something to the end of `sharing -l | grep path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this:

```
sharing -l | sed -En '/^path:/{ s/^path:[[:blank:]]*//; s/[[:blank:]]+/\\&/g; p;}'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you have save many hairs on my balding head.

Comment: I went by title of question that just mentions stripping spaces in the beginning.

Comment: Fair enough, I have modified my `sed` command to address escaping space as well.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
sharing -l | awk '{$2=$2"\\";$3=$3"\\";sub(/^path: +/,"")} 1'
```

Comment: @Jordon Eunson, I thought you need output as `/Volumes/Storage\ A/File\ Server/` which my command is giving; is it not the case?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the white spaces escaped:

```
$ sharing -l | sed -n 's/^path:[[:space:]]*//p'
/Volumes/Storage A/File Server/
```

and if you do:

```
$ sharing -l |  awk 'sub(/^path:[[:space:]]*/,""){gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"\\\\&"); print}'
/Volumes/Storage\ A/File\ Server/
```